# Knockoutjs keeps asking for customer().fullname

Tags: knockout.js, magento2.4

I am writing a module where I am displaying the date/time of the last login inside a block in the customer account sidebar. It works well with plain php but I ran in the issue of the page being cached. Which causes the date only being displayed after a reload. To prevent this, I want to get the information via knockout js inside the blocks template phtml. I am fairly new to ko and I really don't have a clue what the issue is.

**Preconditions**

I have set up a controller which returns a json with all the data from my custom block.

**Template code**

```js
<div data-bind="scope: 'kamephis_avatar'">
    <div data-bind="html: info_block"></div>
    <div>
        <span>Last Login Date: </span>
        <span data-bind="text: last_login_date"></span>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'uiComponent',
        'knockout',
        'jquery'
    ], function (Component, ko, $) {
        'use strict';

        var avatarData = {};

        $.ajax({
            url: '/kamephis_avatar/avatar/index',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
                avatarData = response;
            },
            async: false
        });

        ko.components.register('kamephis-avatar', {
            viewModel: {
                initialize: function () {
                    this.last_login_date = ko.observable(avatarData.last_login_date);
                }
            },
            template: {
                element: 'kamephis-avatar-template'
            }
        });

        ko.applyBindings();
    });
</script>
```

**In the customer account, I am getting the following console errors:**

```
knockout.js:3753 Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function(){return customer().fullname }"
Message: customer is not defined
    at if (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:3221:28), <anonymous>:3:55)
    at ko.computed.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved (knockout.js:4820:71)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate_CallReadThenEndDependencyDetection (knockout.js:2331:115)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate_CallReadWithDependencyDetection (knockout.js:2288:41)
    at Function.evaluateImmediate (knockout.js:2253:40)
    at ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable (knockout.js:2085:40)
    at init (knockout.js:4819:32)
    at knockout.js:3730:58
    at Object.ignore (knockout.js:1563:45)
    at knockout.js:3729:60
if @ VM16960:3
ko.computed.disposeWhenNodeIsRemoved @ knockout.js:4820
evaluateImmediate_CallReadThenEndDependencyDetection @ knockout.js:2331
evaluateImmediate_CallReadWithDependencyDetection @ knockout.js:2288
evaluateImmediate @ knockout.js:2253
ko.computed.ko.dependentObservable @ knockout.js:2085
init @ knockout.js:4819
(anonymous) @ knockout.js:3730
ignore @ knockout.js:1563
(anonymous) @ knockout.js:3729
arrayForEach @ knockout.js:168
applyBindingsToNodeInternal @ knockout.js:3715
applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal @ knockout.js:3573
applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal @ knockout.js:3555
applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal @ knockout.js:3576
applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal @ knockout.js:3555
applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal @ knockout.js:3576
applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal @ knockout.js:3555
applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal @ knockout.js:3576
applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal @ knockout.js:3555
applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal @ knockout.js:3576
applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal @ knockout.js:3555
applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal @ knockout.js:3576
applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal @ knockout.js:3555
applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal @ knockout.js:3576
applyBindingsToDescendantsInternal @ knockout.js:3555
applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal @ knockout.js:3576
ko.applyBindings @ knockout.js:3807
_super @ wrapper.js:73
applyBindings @ bound-nodes.js:118
(anonymous) @ wrapper.js:78
(anonymous) @ (index):679
execCb @ require.js:1696
check @ require.js:883
(anonymous) @ require.js:1139
(anonymous) @ require.js:134
(anonymous) @ require.js:1189
each @ require.js:59
emit @ require.js:1188
check @ require.js:938
(anonymous) @ require.js:1139
(anonymous) @ require.js:134
(anonymous) @ require.js:1189
each @ require.js:59
emit @ require.js:1188
check @ require.js:938
enable @ require.js:1176
init @ require.js:788
(anonymous) @ require.js:1014
(anonymous) @ require.js:134
(anonymous) @ mixins.js:129
execCb @ require.js:1696
check @ require.js:883
(anonymous) @ require.js:1139
(anonymous) @ require.js:134
(anonymous) @ require.js:1189
each @ require.js:59
emit @ require.js:1188
check @ require.js:938
(anonymous) @ require.js:1139
(anonymous) @ require.js:134
(anonymous) @ require.js:1189
each @ require.js:59
emit @ require.js:1188
check @ require.js:938
enable @ require.js:1176
init @ require.js:788
(anonymous) @ require.js:1014
(anonymous) @ require.js:134
(anonymous) @ mixins.js:129
execCb @ require.js:1696
check @ require.js:883
(anonymous) @ require.js:1139
(anonymous) @ require.js:134
(anonymous) @ require.js:1189
each @ require.js:59
emit @ require.js:1188
check @ require.js:938
(anonymous) @ require.js:1139
(anonymous) @ require.js:134
(anonymous) @ require.js:1189
each @ require.js:59
emit @ require.js:1188
check @ require.js:938
enable @ require.js:1176
init @ require.js:788
(anonymous) @ require.js:1014
(anonymous) @ require.js:134
(anonymous) @ mixins.js:129
execCb @ require.js:1696
check @ require.js:883
(anonymous) @ require.js:1139
(anonymous) @ require.js:134
(anonymous) @ require.js:1189
each @ require.js:59
emit @ require.js:1188
check @ require.js:938
enable @ require.js:1176
init @ require.js:788
callGetModule @ require.js:1203
completeLoad @ require.js:1590
onScriptLoad @ require.js:1717
load (async)
req.load @ require.js:1942
load @ require.js:1685
load @ require.js:834
fetch @ require.js:824
check @ require.js:856
enable @ require.js:1176
enable @ require.js:1557
(anonymous) @ require.js:1161
(anonymous) @ require.js:134
each @ require.js:59
enable @ require.js:1113
init @ require.js:788
(anonymous) @ require.js:1460
setTimeout (async)
req.nextTick @ require.js:1815
localRequire @ require.js:1449
load @ mixins.js:128
(anonymous) @ require.js:1095
(anonymous) @ require.js:134
on @ require.js:517
callPlugin @ require.js:955
fetch @ require.js:824
check @ require.js:856
enable @ require.js:1176
enable @ require.js:1557
(anonymous) @ require.js:1161
(anonymous) @ require.js:134
each @ require.js:59
enable @ require.js:1113
init @ require.js:788
callGetModule @ require.js:1203
completeLoad @ require.js:1590
onScriptLoad @ require.js:1717
load (async)
req.load @ require.js:1942
load @ require.js:1685
load @ require.js:834
fetch @ require.js:824
check @ require.js:856
enable @ require.js:1176
enable @ require.js:1557
(anonymous) @ require.js:1161
(anonymous) @ require.js:134
each @ require.js:59
enable @ require.js:1113
init @ require.js:788
(anonymous) @ require.js:1460
setTimeout (async)
req.nextTick @ require.js:1815
localRequire @ require.js:1449
load @ mixins.js:128
(anonymous) @ require.js:1095
(anonymous) @ require.js:134
on @ require.js:517
callPlugin @ require.js:955
fetch @ require.js:824
check @ require.js:856
enable @ require.js:1176
enable @ require.js:1557
(anonymous) @ require.js:1161
(anonymous) @ require.js:134
each @ require.js:59
enable @ require.js:1113
init @ require.js:788
callGetModule @ require.js:1203
completeLoad @ require.js:1590
onScriptLoad @ require.js:1717
load (async)
req.load @ require.js:1942
load @ require.js:1685
load @ require.js:834
fetch @ require.js:824
check @ require.js:856
enable @ require.js:1176
enable @ require.js:1557
(anonymous) @ require.js:1161
(anonymous) @ require.js:134
each @ require.js:59
enable @ require.js:1113
init @ require.js:788
(anonymous) @ require.js:1460
setTimeout (async)
req.nextTick @ require.js:1815
localRequire @ require.js:1449
load @ mixins.js:128
(anonymous) @ require.js:1095
(anonymous) @ require.js:134
on @ require.js:517
callPlugin @ require.js:955
fetch @ require.js:824
check @ require.js:856
enable @ require.js:1176
enable @ require.js:1557
(anonymous) @ require.js:1161
(anonymous) @ require.js:134
each @ require.js:59
enable @ require.js:1113
init @ require.js:788
callGetModule @ require.js:1203
completeLoad @ require.js:1590
onScriptLoad @ require.js:1717
load (async)
req.load @ require.js:1942
load @ require.js:1685
load @ require.js:834
fetch @ require.js:824
check @ require.js:856
enable @ require.js:1176
enable @ require.js:1557
(anonymous) @ require.js:1161
(anonymous) @ require.js:134
each @ require.js:59
enable @ require.js:1113
init @ require.js:788
(anonymous) @ require.js:1460
setTimeout (async)
req.nextTick @ require.js:1815
localRequire @ require.js:1449
requirejs @ require.js:1797
(anonymous) @ (index):645
knockout.js:3620 Uncaught Error: You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element.
    at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.js:3620:35)
    at applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal (knockout.js:3573:56)
    at ko.applyBindings (knockout.js:3807:21)
    at _super (wrapper.js:73:35)
    at Object.applyBindings (bound-nodes.js:118:26)
    at Object.applyBindings (wrapper.js:78:32)
    at bootstrap.js:21:8
    at Object.execCb (require.js:1696:33)
    at Module.check (require.js:883:51)
    at Module.<anonymous> (require.js:1139:34)
```

Comment: You need to add in the code that has customer in it.  Also, your last_login_date observable won't update after the Ajax returns as you are not passing the value into the observable on the success()

Comment: This error doesn't belong with the code you provided. Search your project for `customer().fullname` to see what component is providing the error.